# How can I enable my custom ExceptionMapper in TomEE?

Tags: java, rest, apache-tomee

I have a custom Mapper for a specific business exception like this:

```
@Provider
@Singleton
public class MissingHeaderExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MissingHeaderException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MissingHeaderException ex) {
```

It is not invoked when the exception is thrown.

I have found a lot of discussion online about this problem in TomEE. a lot of answers provided were apparently for experts, because I really don't understand what they were talking about.

- Do I need to have a config file?
- if Yes, name of the config, where should I put it, where can I find a sample of this config file?
- If I have to use a class to register this custom ExceptionMapper, how should I do it?

I have tried to add an Application object to the project like this page suggests

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_defresource_exception_mapper.html

I also followed the example from this page:
https://javaspecialist.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/rest-api-exception-handling-using-jax-rs-in-jee-6/

There are tons of ExceptionMapper sample code online, but how come none of them works for TomEE. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I added the following config in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>namespace.MissingHeaderExceptionMapper</param-value>
</context-param>
```

with a simple service

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public void test() {
    throw new MissingHeaderException("test");
}
```

When I tried to call this endpoint, I hit this line, and the constructor of my MissingHeaderException, but it never hit the constructor of the Mapper. The code just continues, and I get this

```
WebApplicationException has been caught, status: 500
```

In the debugger console, I am getting

14-Dec-2015 21:46:13.804 WARNING [http-bio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper.toResponse namespace.MissingHeaderException
at namespace.myService.test

but my Mapper is actually formatting a nice error response like this:

```
@Provider
public final class MissingHeaderExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MissingHeaderException> {

    public MissingHeaderExceptionMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MissingHeaderException ex) {

        ErrorPayload errorPayload = new ErrorPayload();
        errorPayload.setCode("8001008");
        errorPayload.setMessage("Header " + ex.getHeaderName() + " is missing");
        return Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).
                entity(errorPayload).
                type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).
                build();
    }
}
```

I didn't expect just a line of text, even it is, the status code is not right either....

something is wrong, but I am so confused now. Java eco-system really has no intention to make it easier to understand... :(

Comment: It sounds like you are using JAX-RS.  Typically the goal is to make your JAX-RS container (e.g. Application / ResourceConfig / etc.) aware of the ExceptionMapper.  Can you post your web.xml file (if you have one)?  If you don't, do you know where you initialize and configure JAX-RS?

Comment: @Pace Hi I didn't have one, since you mentioned it, I did some search and put this code in web.xml:     <context-param> <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>   <param-value>MyNameSpace.exceptions.MissingHeaderExceptionMapper</param-value>   </context-param>, but it still doesn't work. I am currently using a WebFilter to catch each operation, I can hit the filter code, the logic seems to be fine, but after the exception is thrown, it's just gone.

Comment: @Tiny I am writing a restful service not JSF, I think I am supposed to throw WebApplicationException, not ApplicationException. or am I misunderstanding what you are proposing?

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHH, I finally figured it out!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it's the stupid TomEE configuration problem. So difficult to discover. I am missing the openejb-jar.xml, and I need to put <openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <pojo-deployment class-name="jaxrs-application">
        <properties>
            cxf.jaxrs.providers = namespace.MissingHeaderExceptionMapper
        </properties>
    </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>